# restrict previous dates in datetimelocal input

Tags: html, datetime-local

I have used following code snippet to restrict previous dates in datetimelocal input. It works fine but it returns seconds and milliseconds too. How to get only hours and minutes?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let elem = document.getElementById("application_start_date")
    const iso = new Date().toISOString();
    const minDate = iso.substring(0, iso.length - 1);
    elem.value = minDate
    elem.min = minDate
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the substring parameters like this

If you want date and hous+minutes,

```
const mn = iso.substring(0,iso.length -5) //2022-02-17T05:34:06
```

If you want time only then,

```
const mn = iso.substring(11,iso.length -5) //05:34:06
```